# android google map draw path error

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm developing an android app that contains google map drawing path.

and I use method like this

```
      private void DrawPath(GeoPoint src, GeoPoint dest, int color,
          MapView mMapView01) {



        // connect to map web service
        StringBuilder urlString = new StringBuilder();
        urlString.append("http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&hl=en");
        urlString.append("&saddr=");//from
        urlString.append( Double.toString((double)src.getLatitudeE6()/1.0E6 ));
        urlString.append(",");
        urlString.append( Double.toString((double)src.getLongitudeE6()/1.0E6 ));
        urlString.append("&daddr=");//to
        urlString.append( Double.toString((double)dest.getLatitudeE6()/1.0E6 ));
        urlString.append(",");
        urlString.append( Double.toString((double)dest.getLongitudeE6()/1.0E6 ));
        urlString.append("&ie=UTF8&0&om=0&output=kml");
        Log.d("xxx","URL="+urlString.toString());

        //System.out.println(urlString);
        // get the kml (XML) doc. And parse it to get the coordinates(direction route).
        Document doc = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection= null;
        URL url = null;
        try
        {
          url = new URL(urlString.toString());
          urlConnection=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
          urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
          urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
          urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
          urlConnection.connect();

          DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
          DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
          doc = db.parse(urlConnection.getInputStream());

          if(doc.getElementsByTagName("GeometryCollection").getLength()>0)
          {
            //String path = doc.getElementsByTagName("GeometryCollection").item(0).getFirstChild().getFirstChild().getNodeName();
            String path = doc.getElementsByTagName("GeometryCollection").item(0).getFirstChild().getFirstChild().getFirstChild().getNodeValue() ;
            Log.d("xxx","path="+ path);
            String [] pairs = path.split(" ");
            String[] lngLat = pairs[0].split(","); // lngLat[0]=longitude lngLat[1]=latitude lngLat[2]=height
            // src
            GeoPoint startGP = new GeoPoint((int)(Double.parseDouble(lngLat[1])*1E6),(int)(Double.parseDouble(lngLat[0])*1E6));
            //mMapView01.getOverlays().add(overlayitem);
            GeoPoint gp1;
            GeoPoint gp2 = startGP;
            for(int i=1;i<pairs.length;i++) // the last one would be crash
            {
              lngLat = pairs[i].split(",");
              gp1 = gp2;
              // watch out! For GeoPoint, first:latitude, second:longitude
              gp2 = new GeoPoint((int)(Double.parseDouble(lngLat[1])*1E6),(int)(Double.parseDouble(lngLat[0])*1E6));
              mMapView01.getOverlays().add(new MapRouteOverlay(gp1,gp2,2,color));
              Log.d("xxx","pair:" + pairs[i]);
            }
            //mMapView01.getOverlays().add(new MapRouteOverlay(dest,dest, 3)); // use the default color
          }
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e)
        {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (ParserConfigurationException e)
        {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (SAXException e)
        {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }


      }
}
```

the line

```
  Log.d("xxx","URL="+urlString.toString());
```

shows that the url is complete correct with browser like this

http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&hl=en&saddr=25.051393,121.560243&daddr=25.052742,121.558137&ie=UTF8&0&om=0&output=kml

and the strangest thing is that

It works fine 3days ago!!

But yesterday,it become report an error like this

in line

```
doc = db.parse(urlConnection.getInputStream());
```

[image]

it jumps to Exception handling right away

any suggestion?

thanks for your great help!